# Import numpy with python 2.6

Tags: python, import, numpy

This may be a simple question, but I am stuck: I want to use numpy with Python 2.6. I appended the path where the numpy folder is located:

C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\

and also the path for the numpy folder itself

C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\numpy

However, this error message appears

```
x=np.array([[7,8,5][3,5,7]],np.int32)


   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
        x=np.array([[7,8,5][3,5,7]],np.int32)
    NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Could you help me with this?

Comment: Did you actually `import numpy as np`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You shouldn't have to add those things to the path.  Python knows where to look for installed modules as long as you have C:\Python26 in the path.

Sven Marnach was asking if you did it like this:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([[7,8,5],[3,5,7]],np.int32)
```

Edit:  I just noticed you left out a comma in your array declaration also...fixed it in the above